# How can i outsource the code of 2 classes into a new one, so that both classes can call the method

Tags: java, csv, generics

I have 2 classes which are doing basically the same. They both generate a list with Person opjects that are filled with data. DKKRPerson inherits from GKVPerson and contains even more data than a GKVPerson. My goal is to outsource the code of the classes to a new one, so that both classes can call the method without writing the code twice.

Here is class Nr. 1:

```
public class GenerateGkvPerson {

Random randomItem = new Random();

public List<GKVPerson> generatedGkvPersons(List<PersonFirstName> personFirstNames, List<Street> streets, List<PersonLastName> personLastNames, List<City> cities) {

    List<GKVPerson> gkvPersons = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Number of GKVPersons, who will be generated: ");
    int numberOfRecords = in.nextInt();

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfRecords; i++) {
        int matching = randomItem.nextInt(personFirstNames.size());
        int matchingBirthData = randomItem.nextInt(cities.size());
        int matchingCityZipCode = randomItem.nextInt(cities.size());
        int birthYear = generateRandomNumber(1973, 2021);

        GKVPerson person = new GKVPerson();

        person.setId(i + 1);
        person.setFirstName(personFirstNames.get(matching).getFirstName());
        person.setGender(personFirstNames.get(matching).getGender());
        person.setLastName(personLastNames.get(randomItem.nextInt(personLastNames.size())).getLastName());
        person.setFirstBirthName(personFirstNames.get(matching).getFirstName());
        person.setLastBirthName(personLastNames.get(randomItem.nextInt(personLastNames.size())).getLastName());
        person.setBirthDate(generateBirthDate() + birthYear);
        person.setBirthYear(birthYear);
        person.setLivingPlaceCityNow(cities.get(matchingCityZipCode).getCity());
        person.setLivingPlaceStreetNameNow(streets.get(randomItem.nextInt(streets.size())).getStreetName());
        person.setLivingPlaceHouseNumberNow(generateRandomNumber(1, 200));
        person.setLivingPlaceZipCodeNow(cities.get(matchingCityZipCode).getZipCode());
        person.setBirthPlaceCityName(cities.get(matchingBirthData).getCity());
        person.setBirthPlaceZipCode(cities.get(matchingBirthData).getZipCode());

        gkvPersons.add(person);
    }
    return gkvPersons;
}

public static int generateRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
    return (int) (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

public String generateBirthDate() {
    String birthDate = "";
    int month = generateRandomNumber(1, 12);
    int day;

        if (month % 2 == 0) {
            day = generateRandomNumber(1, 30);
        } else if (month == 2) {
            day = generateRandomNumber(1, 28);
        } else {
            day = generateRandomNumber(1, 31);
        }

        if (month >= 10 && day >= 10) {
            birthDate = day + "." + month + ".";
        } else if (month < 10 && day < 10) {
            birthDate = "0" + day + "." + "0" + month + ".";
        } else if (month < 10 && day >= 10) {
            birthDate = day + "." + "0" + month + "." ;
        } else if (month >= 10 && day < 10) {
            birthDate = "0" + day + "." + month + ".";
        }

    return birthDate;
}
```

and here is class Nr. 2:

```
public class GenerateDkkrPerson {

Random randomItem = new Random();

public List<DKKRPerson> generateDkkrPerson(List<PersonFirstName> personFirstNames, List<Street> streets, List<PersonLastName> personLastNames, List<City> cities) {

    List<DKKRPerson> dkkrPersons = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.printf("Number of DKKRPersons, who will be generated: ");
    int numberOfRecords = in.nextInt();

    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfRecords; i++) {
        int matching = randomItem.nextInt(personFirstNames.size());
        int matchingBirthData = randomItem.nextInt(cities.size());
        int matchingCityZipCode = randomItem.nextInt(cities.size());
        int birthYear = generateRandomNumber(1973, 2021);
        int matchingDiagnoseCity = randomItem.nextInt(cities.size());
        int matchingParentsCityData = randomItem.nextInt(cities.size());
        int matchingParentsStreetData = randomItem.nextInt(streets.size());
        int matchingParentsHouseNumber = generateRandomNumber(1, 200);

        DKKRPerson dkkrPerson = new DKKRPerson();

        dkkrPerson.setId(i + 1);
        dkkrPerson.setFirstName(personFirstNames.get(matching).getFirstName());
        dkkrPerson.setGender(personFirstNames.get(matching).getGender());
        dkkrPerson.setLastName(personLastNames.get(randomItem.nextInt(personLastNames.size())).getLastName());
        dkkrPerson.setFirstBirthName(personFirstNames.get(matching).getFirstName());
        dkkrPerson.setLastBirthName(personLastNames.get(randomItem.nextInt(personLastNames.size())).getLastName());
        dkkrPerson.setBirthDate(generateBirthDate() + birthYear);
        dkkrPerson.setBirthYear(birthYear);
        dkkrPerson.setLivingPlaceCityNow(cities.get(matchingCityZipCode).getCity());
        dkkrPerson.setLivingPlaceStreetNameNow(streets.get(randomItem.nextInt(streets.size())).getStreetName());
        dkkrPerson.setLivingPlaceHouseNumberNow(generateRandomNumber(1, 200));
        dkkrPerson.setLivingPlaceZipCodeNow(cities.get(matchingCityZipCode).getZipCode());
        dkkrPerson.setBirthPlaceCityName(cities.get(matchingBirthData).getCity());
        dkkrPerson.setBirthPlaceZipCode(cities.get(matchingBirthData).getZipCode());
        dkkrPerson.setDiagnoseStreetName(streets.get(randomItem.nextInt(streets.size())).getStreetName());
        dkkrPerson.setDiagnoseHouseNumber(generateRandomNumber(1, 200));
        dkkrPerson.setDiagnoseCityName(cities.get(matchingDiagnoseCity).getCity());
        dkkrPerson.setDiagnoseZipCode(cities.get(matchingDiagnoseCity).getZipCode());
        dkkrPerson.setParentsStreetName(streets.get(matchingParentsStreetData).getStreetName());
        dkkrPerson.setParentsHouseNumber(matchingParentsHouseNumber);
        dkkrPerson.setParentsCityName(cities.get(matchingParentsCityData).getCity());
        dkkrPerson.setParentsZipCode(cities.get(matchingParentsCityData).getZipCode());
        dkkrPerson.setMotherStreetName(streets.get(matchingParentsStreetData).getStreetName());
        dkkrPerson.setMotherHouseNumber(matchingParentsHouseNumber);
        dkkrPerson.setMotherCityName(cities.get(matchingParentsCityData).getCity());
        dkkrPerson.setMotherZipCode(cities.get(matchingParentsCityData).getZipCode());
        dkkrPerson.setFatherStreetName(streets.get(matchingParentsStreetData).getStreetName());
        dkkrPerson.setFatherHouseNumber(matchingParentsHouseNumber);
        dkkrPerson.setFatherCityName(cities.get(matchingParentsCityData).getCity());
        dkkrPerson.setFatherZipCode(cities.get(matchingParentsCityData).getZipCode());

        dkkrPersons.add(dkkrPerson);
    }
    return dkkrPersons;
}

public static int generateRandomNumber(int min, int max) {
    return (int) (Math.random() * (max - min)) + min;
}

public String generateBirthDate() {
    String birthDate = "";
    int month = generateRandomNumber(1, 12);
    int day;

    if (month % 2 == 0) {
        day = generateRandomNumber(1, 30);
    } else if (month == 2) {
        day = generateRandomNumber(1, 28);
    } else {
        day = generateRandomNumber(1, 31);
    }

    if (month >= 10 && day >= 10) {
        birthDate = day + "." + month + ".";
    } else if (month < 10 && day < 10) {
        birthDate = "0" + day + "." + "0" + month + ".";
    } else if (month < 10 && day >= 10) {
        birthDate = day + "." + "0" + month + "." ;
    } else if (month >= 10 && day < 10) {
        birthDate = "0" + day + "." + month + ".";
    }

    return birthDate;
}
```

Maybe someone of you can help me

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to create a class, declare an object of the class, and then call the desired method from that class? Another way is to write the method to a parent class and then extend that class onto classes as required.

Comment: I tried to do this but i don't exactly know how to do it, so it didn't work like it should

Answer (score 0):

Refactoring is the word you are looking for, in place of "outsourcing".  Be fearless about refactoring if you keep copies of key stages (or commit them) and the more so as you have test coverage.

Good impulse to refactor those two classes into one inheritance relationship like `DkkrPerson` inherits from `GkvPerson`.  Thus make `GenerateDkkrPerson` inherit from `GenerateGkvPerson`.  This is supported by eyeballing the code and seeing more `D` than `G` code.

So take those two class files and compare them with some tool like WinMerge; or eyeball it line by line because the settings seem to use nearly identical order.  Figure out how to encapsulate common calls into methods such that both classes can do that chunk of work in one class.  Then what is left is less overwhelming.

DRY: You are repeating yourself with all the calls to `dkkrPerson` methods.  And there is a pattern here where `GenerateDkkrPerson` doesn't need to know all that stuff about how `DkkrPerson` works.  So the remedy is to find a way to put all that logic into `DkkrPerson`.  I think a lot of stuff including the `matching...` declarations can all be moved into a method or two in `DkkrPerson`.

Likewise with `GvdPerson`.

Maybe even do that DRY refactoring and code responsibility refactoring before doing the `GenerateGkvPerson` inheritance refactoring.  A lot of the latter might be simplified by the former.